# How to check a file system corruption in USB with FATFS?

Tags: c, embedded, filesystems, stm32, fatfs

I want to know is there a way to the corruption of file system in stm32 with fatfs.
I tried using (_FS_NOFSINFO =  1) and f_getfree but this function takes a lot of time to execute and doesn't tell if anything is wrong or not.

Comment: Presumably you are specifically talking about the [ELM FatFs library](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) rather then FAT file system generically?  ELM FatFs is included with STM32Cube for example.  It has no journaling, is not power-fail safe and has no error check or repair function (`chkdsk`).  For removable storage, you can of course run such a tool on a PC, for non removable storage, it is hardly fit for purpose.  The ELM site includes details of the FAT file-system that you might use to create your own integrity check and repair, but it is no simple undertaking.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am trying to know is there any reference to check for integrity and how to do it. I don't want to repair usb drives like chkdsk I just want to know if anything is wrong with file system.